Convertir un formated text field de una fecha en un Time Stamp
Estoy haciendo un curso de Iniciación a Java, estoy recogiendo los fatos de un formulario de Mantenimiento y tengo éste error en éste código:
this.registroHabitacionActivo.setData(id,
                                    
Integer.valueOf(this.textIdPaciente.getText()).longValue(), 
                                    
Integer.valueOf(this.textIdHabitacion.getText()).longValue(),

this.textFechaEntrada.getText(),

this.textObservaciones.getText());

El error que me da el NetBeans es que necesito long,long,long,Timestamp y String y la fecha es un texto. Y no sé convertirlo.

¿Que formato de fecha estas introduciendo? , agrega un ejemplo

Debes de convertir primero la fecha que ingresas a tipo Date y posteriormente puedes obtener el Timestamp.
Importante es conocer el formato del texto que ingresaras, por ejemplo si usas este tipo de hora y fecha:
"14/02/1990 12:02:33"

definirías el formato:
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Por lo tanto este sería el código para convertir a Timestamp:
String formatoFechaHora = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoFechaHora);
//*Convierte a Date   
Date parsedDate = myDateFormat.parse(this.textFechaEntrada.getText());
//*Convierte a Timestamp 
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());

System.out.println("Valor Timestamp: " + timestamp);


Muchísimas gracias. Lo probaré ahora mismo.

Lo he solucionado porque en el insert de la cadena SQL va unido el CURRENT TIMESTAMP al idhabitacion y lo inserta automáticamente cuando al paciente se le asigna la habitación. Así pues aquí sobraba.
this.registroHabitacionActivo.setData(
    Long.valueOf(this.textIdPaciente.getText()).longValue(),
    Long.valueOf(this.textIdHabitacion.getText()).longValue(),
    this.textObservaciones.getText());

